# Processor working on low frequencies only

Tags: laptop, cpu, intel-core-i7, dell-xps

I am using a Dell XPS 17 laptop, which has Intel Core i7 2670QM processor.  The problem is, that i cant get it work on higher frequency than 800 (multiplier x8).  I doesn't matter how i load CPU it stays at 800 all the time.  Sometimes it goes up at boot but then drops down again. I cant play games normally, even browsing with 10+ tabs starts to become pain.

I did clean PC but that didn't help. My local technician said he didn't see any problem, but then again i don't think he only checked CPU load but not actual frequency.

One thing that is weird is that my (quite decent) battery just died on one day.  And now i am using my laptop without a battery.

So what popped in my mind is maybe there is something wrong with laptops electric flow and my CPU isn't getting enough voltage?  In that case i am looking for suggestions on how could i check it.

If anything else could be done to make my CPU work properly im all open for any tips or suggestions.

Thnx

Comment: Without seeing the laptop it is hard to say, but a broken CPU fan might explain your issues.

Comment: run prime95, and watch your scaling with cpuz. it should change. as a general rule, digital devices don’t run at all when their power needs are not (mostly) met. also check your advanced power settings, and make sure that you are not explicitly throttling it. that would explain why boot is the only time you see it go up.

Comment: Is this an older machine, maybe the heat vents are stuffed with dust/ dirt. This causes the laptop to clock down, event to the lowest level. I has this with an HP machine an needed to open it to clean it up.

Comment: make sure the powerplan is NOT set to "power saving" mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your power management driver. There will be some dell application for it probably which may replace the default windows power settings, so check there if there is some processor performance settings which could cause it. Usually there is a special menu on the battery/charger tray icon to access these settings. And yes check with the CPUz if anything changes.

Comment: I think i might found the problem.  After installing Dell Quickset application it said that my AC adapter is not recognized and all my settings have been lowered. So now i have to look for problem deeper in hardware since i know for a fact that my adapter is fine, since my brother has laptop with same adapter and with hes it gives same error.